# JavaScript and Node.JS -- unable to understand why variable in callback is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

So I am starting to learn NodeJS and creating a simple HTTP server as given in The Node Beginner book. I have a `Router` object, which contains a routing `table`, which maps pathnames to the functions to be called. This is achieved by a key value object.

Now, my `Server` object has a `router` member which points to the above mentioned object. (For loose coupling, have kept the Router and Server separete), and a `start()` method which starts the server. Which is as given below:

```
Server.prototype.start = function() {
    var myRouter = this.router;
    http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname; 
        res.write(myRouter.route(path, null));
        res.end();
    }).listen(80);
};
```

Now I have created a `myRouter` variable which points to the `router` reference of the `Server` object, and then in the `createServer` function, performing the routing using it's `route()` function. This code works. However, if I omit creating the `myRouter` variable part and directly perform the routing in `createServer` like this:

```
res.write(this.router.route(path, null));
```

It says `this.router` is undefined. I know this has something to do with scope, as the function supplied to `createServer` executes later whenever a request is received, however, I am not able to understand how creating `myRouter` solves this problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem has less to do with scope and more with how `this` works.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: Thank you, to you both. Will read up the answer suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable  `myRourer` resolves the problem because functions remember the environment, in which they are created ([Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)). Therefore the callback knows the `myRouter` variable

Another solution for your problem could be to to set the this value of the callback to a specific object with the bind method ([bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)).

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname; 
    res.write(this.router.route(path, null));
    res.end();
}.bind(this)).listen(80);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In the request callback ,

function(req, res) {
        var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname; 
        res.write(myRouter.route(path, null));
        res.end();
    }

'this' doesnot refer to your outer Server. To use this inside this callback use bind.

Server.prototype.start = function() {
    var myRouter = this.router;
    http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname; 
        res.write(myRouter.route(path, null));
        res.end();
    }.bind(this)).listen(80);
};
```

Comment: True, but then how `myRouter` refers correctly?

Comment: Your myRouter is declared inside server and not insid createserver callbacl
Thats why

Comment: Why do you format your whole post as code?

Comment: Sorry Will take  care of it